# Correlated Sub-Query; payments in any month and year are more than twice the average for that month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Full Question**: Which payments in any month and year are more than twice the average for that month and year

(i.e. compare all payments in Oct 2004 with the average payment for Oct 2004? Order the results by the date of the payment. You will need to use the date functions.)

My attempt at sql

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @StartDate)

SELECT checkNumber, amount AS avg_payment, paymentDate
FROM Payments 
WHERE paymentDate BETWEEN '2004-10-01' AND '2004-10-31'
AND amount > 2 * (SELECT AVG(amount)
                    FROM Payments 
GROUP BY paymentDate, checkNumber, amount)
```

Database here : http://richardtwatson.com/dm6e/images/general/ClassicModels.png

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're not actually correlating the subquery. (Hint: if you were, you wouldn't actually need the `group by`).

Comment: Been attempting this question for a couple hours too long now, my mind is scattered with the correct rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problem is easily handled using window functions:

```
SELECT p.checkNumber, p.amount, p.paymentDate
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             AVG(p.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(p.paymentDate), MONTH(p.PaymentDate)) as avg_ym
      FROM Payments p
     ) p
WHERE p.paymentDate BETWEEN '2004-10-01' AND '2004-10-31' AND
      p.amount > 2 * avg_ym;
```

As mentioned in a comment, your query doesn't work first because there is no correlation clause and second because it will return an error because too many rows are returned.

Comment: +1 definitely window functions, could placing the "WHERE p.paymentDate BETWEEN D and D" in the derived table rather than the outer select be more performant?

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the quick reply. But i am getting a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.' with your query.

Comment: @b.le there was a parenthesis missing before as I just added it

Comment: @Matt, thank you so much! I am def going to be practicing more on correlated sub-queries. Jeeze!

Answer (score 0):

You should group by for year(paymentDate), month(paymentDate) not for paymentDate

```
  SELECT checkNumber, amount AS avg_payment, year(paymentDate), month(paymentDate)
  FROM Payments  
  WHERE paymentDate BETWEEN '2004-10-01' AND '2004-10-31'
  AND amount > 2 * (  SELECT AVG(amount)
                      FROM Payments 
                      WHERE paymentDate BETWEEN '2004-10-01' AND '2004-10-31'
                      GROUP BY  year(paymentDate), month(paymentDate),  checkNumber, amount)
```